# Modern Android Sony Walkman app extensions API?

Tags: android, sony, audio-player, android-music-player

Is a not deprecated way to develop app extension for Android Sony Walkman Player?

The Music Infinite API is deprecated, and no longer supported in the Sony Add-on SDK (http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sony-add-on-sdk/)

Comment: I wannt to develop plug-in (extension) to Sony Walkman Application in my Sony Xperia Z1 device.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to what you are trying to develop.

When you say app extension are you referring to an app that runs on the Android Sony Walkman?  Developing for a Walkman device is no different than developing for an Android phone except for the fact that there is no cellular connectivity.  The Sony Add-on SDK is only for developing extensions (apps) that run on companion hardware devices such as the Sony SmartWatch.